# c# remote events

Tags: c#, .net-remoting

I'm trying to do a server client application to learn more about remote programs using c#.

The structure is quite simple.

I have a server which triggers an event when the function updateInventory is called and each client registers a function to the event (using a delegate).

So when any of the client updates the inventory (by calling the updateInventory function) all the clients are warned about it by ways of the event.

Now the problem is that it simply isn't working, when a client calls the updateInventory function the one in the server isn't evoked.

The program has the following 4 componenents:

**The inventoryChangedArgs**

Which is Serializable and serves as argument to the function triggered by the event. I compiled it to .dll and used on the server and the client by "add reference...":

```
using System;

[Serializable]
public class InventoryChangeArgs:EventArgs
{
    private string pno;
    public string Pno
    {
        get
        {
            return pno;
        }
        set
        {
            pno = value;
        }
    }
    private int change;
    public int Change
    {
        get
        {
            return change;
        }
        set
        {
            change = value;
        }
    }
    public InventoryChangeArgs(string pno, int change)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("InventoryChangeArgs constructed");
        this.pno = pno;
        this.change = change;
    }

}
```

**The InventoryManager**

Which declares the delegate, event and states when to trigger the event. The client side has the same class with the only difference being the UpdateInventory content, which is null...everything else is the same.

```
public class InventoryManager:MarshalByRefObject
{
    public delegate string InventoryChangeHandler(object sender, InventoryChangeArgs info);
    public event InventoryChangeHandler Changed;
    public void UpdateInventory(string pno, int change)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("UpdateInveroty has been invoced");
        if (change == 0)
            Console.WriteLine("No changed event");
        else if (Changed != null)
        {
            Changed(this, new InventoryChangeArgs(pno, change));
            Console.WriteLine("Changed event");
        }
    }
}
```

**Event's function on the client side**
Adds to the event the Wan function and sets the Remoting Configuration:

```
class Client
{
    static void Warn(object sender,InventoryChangeArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("It was changed by: {0] the {1}",args.Change,args.Pno);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RemotingConfiguration.Configure("Client.exe.config",false);
        InventoryManager inv=new InventoryManager();
        inv.Changed+=new InventoryManager.InventoryChangeHandler(Warn);
        Console.WriteLine("Client started");
        inv.UpdateInventory("102", 2);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Remote configuration file**
This the remote configuration file for the client, the server is almost the same with the exception of the following lines:

```
...
<application name="Server">
      <service>
        <wellknown
          mode="Singleton"
          type="InventoryManager, InventoryManager"
          objectUri="InventoryManager" />
      </service>
    ...
<channel ref="tcp" port="9000">
```

...

```
<configuration>
  <system.runtime.remoting>
    <application>
      <client>
        <wellknown
          type="InventoryManager, InventoryManager"
          url="tcp://localhost:9000/Server/InventoryManager"
        />
      </client>
      <channels>
        <channel ref="tcp" port="0">
          <serverProviders>
            <formatter ref="binary" typeFilterLevel="Full" />
          </serverProviders>
        </channel>
      </channels>
    </application>
  </system.runtime.remoting>
</configuration>
```

If anyone could give me some assistance I would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Before starting off with .NET Remoting you should read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k.aspx) Clearly stating that it is and abandoned technology: "is not recommended for new development.".

Comment: exact duplicate of [c# remote events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330633/c-remote-events)

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that your problem is, that you do not see that the event is being raised ?  I mean: that the eventhandler (the Warn method in your case) is not executed ?

The reason for that, is that you cannot invoke an event as such on one AppDomain, and suppose that you can handle that event in another AppDomain.
In order to be able to do that, you'll need some kind of 'proxy' object that is `MarshalByRef`'ed as well.

That class can look like this, for instance:

```
public abstract class InventoryManagerUpdatedDelegateObject : MarshalByRefObject
{

    public void InventoryManagerUpdatedCallback( object sender, InventoryChangeArgs e )
    {
          InventoryManagerUpdatedCallbackCore (sender, e);
    }

    protected abstract InventoryManagerUpdatedCallbackCore( object sender, InventoryChangeArgs e );

    public override object InitializeLifetimeService()
    {
         return null;
    }
}
```

This class should be known both on the server and on the client-side.  So, it would be a good idea to put this in the same DLL where your `InventoryChangeArgs` class is defined.

At the client side, you can create an implementation of the above class:

```
public class ConsoleReporter : InventoryManagerUpdatedDelegateObject 
{
    protected override InventoryManagerUpdatedCallbackCore( object sender, InventoryChangeArgs e )
    {
Console.WriteLine("It was changed by: {0] the {1}",args.Change,args.Pno);

    }
}
```

On the client side, do this:

```
class Client
{
    static void Warn(object sender,InventoryChangeArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("It was changed by: {0] the {1}",args.Change,args.Pno);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RemotingConfiguration.Configure("Client.exe.config",false);
        InventoryManager inv=new InventoryManager();

        ConsoleReporter reporter = new ConsoleReporter();

        inv.Changed += reporter.InventoryManagerUpdatedCallback;

        Console.WriteLine("Client started");
        inv.UpdateInventory("102", 2);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```